# Visibility widget do not change ui | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean, visibility

Hi i have **`myWidget`** and i pass the focusNode var to it from **`EditPopUpParent()`** class, when i am focusing **`TextField`** value of **`focusNode.hasFocus`** is changing and i can see it by printing it out by **ElevatedButton** but Container do not show up, why is that?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:prakty/providers/edituser.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class EditPopUpParent extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditPopUpParent({super.key});

  @override
  State<EditPopUpParent> createState() => _EditPopUpParentState();
}

class _EditPopUpParentState extends State<EditPopUpParent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

    List<Widget> editWidgetTypes = [
      Container(),
      editSkillSet(context, focusNode),
    ];

    return Container(child: editWidgetTypes[1]);
  }

  Widget editSkillSet(context, FocusNode focusNode) {
    var skillBoxes = Provider.of<EditUser>(context).skillBoxes;

    final TextEditingController skillCont =
        TextEditingController(text: skillBoxes[1].keys.single);
    return Column(
      children: [
        Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Visibility(
              visible: focusNode.hasFocus,
              child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.abc))),
          TextField(
              controller: skillCont,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              focusNode: focusNode,
              decoration:
                  const InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: 'Type Something')),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(focusNode.hasFocus);
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.check))
        ]),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are expecting to counter the `Visibility` widget on press of `ElevatedButton`

```
 class _EditPopUpParentState extends State<EditPopUpParent> {
  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode(); // Move this outside build

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> editWidgetTypes = [
      Container(),
      editSkillSet(context, focusNode),
    ];

    return Container(child: editWidgetTypes[1]);
  }

  Widget editSkillSet(context, FocusNode focusNode) {
    var skillBoxes = Provider.of<EditUser>(context).skillBoxes;

    final TextEditingController skillCont =
        TextEditingController(text: skillBoxes[1].keys.single);
    return Column(
      children: [
        Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: focusNode.hasFocus,
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: const Icon(Icons.abc),
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: skillCont,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            focusNode: focusNode,
            decoration: const InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: 'Type Something'),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {}); // This line will make sure to rebuild the widget tree on press event
              print(focusNode.hasFocus);
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.check),
          ),
        ]),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing changes

Comment: Actually the `FocusNode` instance you're creating is within the build method of your `_EditPopUpParentState` class. This means that every time build is called, a new instance of `FocusNode` is created and it's value becomes false each time the widget tree is build. So try moving the `FocusNode` outside of the build method.

Comment: thanks for answer, now when i moved FocusNode var it is changing only when i hot restart app, not when i click the button

Comment: after moving focous node outside of the build method are you using `setState(() {});` in `ElevatedButton` `onPressed` event?

Comment: Yes, i am using **```provider```** package so it is notifyListener, i will try to call function **```changeValue```**  after tapping on textfield

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are creating the `FocusNode` locally within the build method of `_EditPopUpParentState`. This means a new `FocusNode` is created each time the build runs.

Try:

```dart
class EditPopUpParent extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditPopUpParent({super.key});

  @override
  State<EditPopUpParent> createState() => _EditPopUpParentState();
}

class _EditPopUpParentState extends State<EditPopUpParent> {


 late FocusNode focusNode;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode = FocusNode(); 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Widget> editWidgetTypes = [
      Container(),
      editSkillSet(context, focusNode),
    ];

    return Container(child: editWidgetTypes[1]);
  }

  Widget editSkillSet(context, focusNode) {
    var skillBoxes = Provider.of<EditUser>(context).skillBoxes;

    final TextEditingController skillCont =
        TextEditingController(text: skillBoxes[1].keys.single);
    return Column(
      children: [
        Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Visibility(
              visible: focusNode.hasFocus,
              child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.abc))),
          TextField(
              controller: skillCont,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              focusNode: focusNode,
              decoration:
                  const InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: 'Type Something')),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(focusNode.hasFocus);
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.check))
        ]),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, now when i moved FocusNode var it is changing only when i hot restart app, not when i click the button